# AngularJS (500 Internal Server Error) for http put

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-http, http-put

I want to update the record to the api.

In my firebug it shows:

> 500 internal server error,
>
> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: `moz-nullprincipal:{f514f16e-f3d3-49f1-99e6-105b2b80f26c}` Line Number 1, Column 1:

and also under put it shows:

> There are no child objects

Here is my code

```
$scope.EditUser = function(){
    $scope.ApplicationId = '7bg67898ewnbqjq65e';

$http.put("mydomain.com/api/Users/UpdateUser", {}, {
   params: { _id: $scope.selectedItem._id, ApplicationId: $scope.ApplicationId, User_Name : $scope.selectedItem.UserName, IsActive: $scope.selectedItem.IsActive }
});
```

Comment: Are you in control of the server side code? Have you tried debugging UpdateUser when that gets hit?

Comment: It solved  $http.put("mydomain.com/api/Users/UpdateUser", {
    _id: $scope.selectedItem._id, ApplicationId: $scope.ApplicationId, User_Name : $scope.selectedItem.UserName, IsActive: $scope.selectedItem.IsActive 
});

Answer (score 1):

This is solved using this

```
$scope.EditUser = function(){
    $scope.ApplicationId = '7bg67898ewnbqjq65e';

$http.put("mydomain.com/api/Users/UpdateUser", {
    _id: $scope.selectedItem._id, ApplicationId: $scope.ApplicationId, User_Name : $scope.selectedItem.UserName, IsActive: $scope.selectedItem.IsActive 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut method to perform PUT request is: $http.put(url, data, [config]);
@user3055606 your Answer is correct.